# How to replace Destry by Update in rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm developping in RoR 4.

In my application, I don't want to delete records, instead I want to update their status to 'Obsolete'. How can I change or re-route the Destroy action ?

Shall I modify the routes.rb :

```
 resources :parameters
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Fred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either remove the destroy route from your routes.rb

```
resources :parameters, except: [:destroy]
```

or, probably better to just modify your destroy method in the controller, e.g.

```
#parameters_controller.rb

    def destroy
      @parameter = Parameter.find(params[:id])
      @parameter.status = 'Obsolete'
      @parameter.save
      redirect_to parameters_path
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution is exactly what I was looking for ! Cheers !